# Why is the output of the function shape function wrong?

Tags: python, pandas

I imported the library panda to read a csv file. After reading it and printing out the shape it shows me (6,1) even the file has 7 rows and 4 columns.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Sari\Desktop\username.csv")
print(data.shape)
print(data.head())
```

The output is the following:

```
(6, 1)
  username;firstname;lastname;age;hobby
0            miau1;miau1;miau11;1;none1
1            miau2;miau2;miau22;2;none2
2            miau3;miau3;miau33;3;noen3
3            miau4;miau4;miau44;4;none4
4            miau5;miau5;miau55;5;none5
```

You can see that the file definitely has more than only one column but I still wonder why it shows only (1,6).

Comment: `csv` means `comma separated values` and `comma` means `,`. You have to set different separator in `read_csv`

Answer (score 2):

The default separator is **,** your file use **;** as separator you need to specify

The **sep** argument will be used as separator

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\Sari\Desktop\username.csv", sep=";")
```